# typescript: How to represent generic child class type in parent class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My code example:

```
class Node {
    brother?: Node;
}

class ChildNode1 extends Node {
    name?: string;
}

const c1 = new ChildNode1();
c1.brother?.name;

class ChildNode2 extends Node {
    count?: string;
}

const c2 = new ChildNode2();
c2.brother?.count;
```

How to let type of property `brother` become the child class type itself?

Is there any generic type like:

```
class Node {
    brother?: ChildClass<Node>;
}
```

Once a class extends `Node`, the `ChildClass<Node>` auto resolve to the child class?

Comment: Does this [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWBLEATW4oB4AqA+aAUAN4EEC+pAZgK4B2wALogPa3QC2iAHorTtAFMuDAbRQxaAgO7QAFADpFYAE4BzCAC5oYWgE8A2gF0AlNAC8+ZgCMAVgMa5ZAIUgDsugA4Ct2UyWjQygIM1MpsoJAwQiJiMC4Qbp4C0P4B0B7UViCIwNBWyswM8ALKAPzQWgjIaBgQOLgEAWQA3OSkEVDQAGLMzOiRKRQEwKwQDN29-VAA6ohFTgVFJeYc3LyyPX21xu2j47xjOsDJZtCSMptTELPzi8XKsjsEBwxHAvL5hfcEAPQ-aQCAHqlAhAA) satisfies your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler one, no need for child class to pass itself.
`typeof this` is exactly what I want!

```
class NodeX {
    brother?: typeof this;
}

class ChildNode1 extends NodeX {
    name?: string;
}

class ChildNode2 extends NodeX {
    count?: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEByD2ATApgDWgbwLACgCQARgE7wAuAFskQPwBc0pAngA7LwBmD5AlhANy4AvrlyhIMAMI8QiBCgCM0ZAA9SyAHaIYctJlx51YALbI60CKSLd1AcwE5hOUfHUXowRQF5o65AHdoKW4ZHXkACgBKew8AOmIyShoYwxN7UXAoQOlZJGQAJiVVDS04XPRsfGB4AFd1UjMLK1t7R2dXUncC718AoJDcvMjovLiSCipqGKra0j4gA)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a generic `Node` like the below :

```
class NodeX<TParent extends NodeX = NodeX<{}>> {
    brother?: TParent;
}

class ChildNode1 extends NodeX<ChildNode1> {
    name?: string;
}

class ChildNode2 extends NodeX<ChildNode2> {
    count?: string;
}
```

The tricky part is to assign a default value as it requires a type argument.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nro43m)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! while I found a simpler just now, you can check it.